# References for variants of Jensen inequality

Tags: real-analysis, reference-request, convex-analysis, integral-inequality, jensen-inequality

I am looking for a **reference** for the following claim:

Let $X$ be a probability space, and let $g:X \to \mathbb [0,\infty) $ be in $L^1(X)$. 
Let $\phi:\mathbb [0,\infty) \to [0,\infty)$ be convex and strictly convex on $[a,\infty)$, for some  $a \in (0,\infty)$, and suppose that $\int_X \phi\circ g=\phi(\int_X g)$.

Then, $\int_X g  \in [a,\infty)$ implies that $g$ is constant a.e. , and $\int_X g  \in (0,a]$ implies that $g \le a$ a.e..

I tried looking at "Real analysis" by Royden, and "Real and complex analysis" by Rudin but couldn't find such things. (not even in the exercises).

I guess I need to look at some book on convex analysis, but I am not familiar with the literature.

Is there any book (or paper) which contains such variants of Jensen?

Comment: Not sure if it will actually be fruitful, but if you're unfamiliar with the literature then Rockafeller's text on Convex Analysis is usually a good place to start.

Comment: Thanks, I will check that.

Comment: You are unlikely to find this result in any book: it is too specialized, and not generally useful.  You will find the basic tools to answer it in Phelps's little _Lectures on Choquet Theory_.  Look for the Krein-Milman theorem and Choquet's  theorem.